# Is it possible to change folder extended properties?

Tags: windows, vba

I've been trying to make archived folders (counting in the 1000's and that are named with unique identifier) human readable without using external databases or applications. I wondered if there is anyway to add/edit additional properties of folders (NOT FILES) in windows. As the name cannot change perhaps I could embed useful information in the 'Customer' sorting field for example.

My experiments and research have turn up completely blank. I assume this information is metadata pulled from within files and as such cannot be used on folders?! If that is the case alternatively could I recreate folder full of shortcuts and embed the info in their?

See below if my post is unclear.

Thanks, Howard

[example folder window with additional sorting properties enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKp4a.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'll work from here (this will prompt in a message the info you want to modify):

```
Sub test()

    'Declare the variables
    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objTopFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim strTopFolderName As String
    Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim objSubFolder As Scripting.Folder

    'Your Top Folder Path
    strTopFolderName = "C:\Documents"

    'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Get the top folder
    Set objTopFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strTopFolderName)

    'with this you will get the folder name or other properties
    For Each objSubFolder In objTopFolder.SubFolders

      MsgBox objSubFolder.Name
      MsgBox objSubFolder.DateCreated

    Next objSubFolder

End Sub
```

FYI - you need the reference to Microsoft Scriptime Runtime enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. This was the first thing i tried. However its the additional fields I want to edit, such as 'group' ect. These cannot be edited with the FSO/Microsoft script runtime as far as I am aware!